# How to make custom DatabaseSchemaProvider compatible with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vsix, sql-server-data-tools

I have built a custom [DatabaseSchemaProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.databaseschemaprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) deployed using a VSIX package.

Under VS2010 and VSTSDB/10 it works great and is used for supporting our custom database language infrastructure in combination with extending the stock [SqlDatabaseSchemaProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.sql.sqldatabaseschemaprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I have been tasked with upgrading the VS Package/VSIX to VS 2012. This is causing two problems

1. Visual Studio seems insistent on upgrading the .dbproj type to
   .sqlproj.
2. After upgrading the project fails to load with the
   following error -

> "Failed to create extension manager for the target
>       platform "**MyCustomSchemaProvider**"

Where **MyCustomSchemaProvider** is my provider type name.

I notice the same types I use in my current VS 2010 project are still available, public and look like they are designed for extension under

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSTSDB

... yet VS does't seem to use these assemblies and instead goes off and loads the incompatible SSDT ones.

How can I prevent VS from mangling my custom schema provider and project and let me continue using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging and digging around with Reflector it would seem MS has shut the door on using their extensible database model. 
The Database Project/dbproj is extensible and customizable under 2010 but not under SSDT/2012. Unfortunate for those of us who built extensions against the technology.